# Reactor changes in Spring Boot 2 M4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have updated from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3 to 2.0.0.M4, which updates Reactor from 3.1.0.M3 to 3.1.0.RC1. This causes my code to break in a number of places.
`Mono.and()` now returns `Mono<Void>`, where previously it returned `Mono<Tuple>`
This is also the case for `Mono.when()`
The following code compiles with the older versions, but not with the new version

```
    Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("A");
    Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("B");

    Mono<String> andResult = m1.and(m2).map(t -> t.getT1() + t.getT2());
    Mono<String> whenResult = Mono.when(m1, m2).map(t -> t.getT1() + t.getT2());
```

Has there been any changes to how this should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when` and `and` that produce `Tuple` have been replaced with `zip`/`zipWith` which are their exact equivalent in the `Flux` API, in order to align the APIs. Remaining `when` and `and` methods, which are found only in `Mono`, are now purely about combining the completion signals, discarding the onNexts (hence they return a `Mono<Void>`)

Answer (score 3):

I switched to Mono.zip(...):

```
mono1.and(mono2).map(...)
```

=>

```
Mono.zip(mono1, mono2).map(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I have been doing the same, but I would like to know why Mono.and have changed. I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation